# Call to undefined function start()

Tags: function, oscommerce

I have face this error in oScommerce

Fatal error: Call to undefined function start() in

Any solution for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may add mor contextual info, for example:

- Your Oscommerce version. I don't find any start() function on [Responsive-osCommerce Community Edition](https://github.com/gburton/Responsive-osCommerce).
- Full error text, because "Call to undefined function start() in" is only a part of it. Next words after "in" are crucial.